# How do I print out the cookies that Mechanized has stored?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm using mechanize to login into a website and then retrieve a page. I'm running into some problems and I suspect this is due to some values in the cookies. When Mechanize logs into a website I assume it stores the cookies.

How do I print out all the data stored in the cookies by Mechanize?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The agent has a cookies methods.

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://www.google.com/")
agent.cookies
agent.cookies.to_s
```

The cookies return is a [Mechanize::Cookies object](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/Mechanize/Cookie.html)

Comment: agent.cookie.each do |cooky|
   puts cooky.value
end