# Mechanize Ruby: Print Cookies

Tags: ruby, mechanize-ruby

When I do agent.get(URL) I get blank results while when I access the URL directly I can see the results. Is it because some cookies are passed to the result page? Can you please help me to print cookies before agent.get(URL) so that I will know what is being passed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print out the cookies that Mechanized has stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566287/how-do-i-print-out-the-cookies-that-mechanized-has-stored)

Comment: I tried that but it shows the default cookies and not that cookies set by the form that i am coming from

Comment: Did you check how the page looks in your browser with javascript turned off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this by adding the cookies before submitting the form.

```
agent = Mechanize.new
cookie = Mechanize::Cookie.new(name: '#{name}', value: '#{value}', domain: '#{domain}', path: '/')
agent.cookie_jar.add(cookie)
```